# iPhone Simulator locks up immediately upon Build / Run

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, simulator

I'm having a problem getting my **MacBook** set up to build **iPhone** **apps** in **xCode**.  The iPhone **Simulator locks up** and shows the "spinning circle" busy icon.

I've tried everything I can think of, including

- resetting the simulator
- tried all of the different hardware options
- tried the two debug build choices in xCode.
- uninstalling the SDK and completely reinstalling

I downloaded the SDK today - "xcode_3.2.2_and_iphone_sdk_3.2_final"

I'm just upgraded from Leopard to **Snow Leopard (10.6.3)**.  I've run all the software updates.  **xCode** version says **3.2.2** (1650)

If it matters, my MacBook is 3-4 years old, 13 inch, dual 2.16 ghz intel cores, 2 gig RAM.  I've never had a single problem with it.

I would be so grateful if anyone can help me

thanks so much,

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the 4.0 one, then try that, if not, then I would install a previous sdk version in a different folder (or rename your current developer folder or delete it, then install the previous version under /Developer) and run that one instead

Answer (score 0):

I just finished installing the 4.0 SDK.  I made a new windows-based iPhone app (HelloWorld) and tried a build/run (Simulator-4.0 | Debug)

Same exact behavior... The simulator appears and the rainbow spinning progress wheel just keeps going and going

I took a sample from the process ("not responding...") but it's pretty big and I don't see any way to attach it to this question.

thanks again

Comment: Hi there, Steve!  I'm having a similar problem right now.  Did you ever find a solution ...?